# Simple route not working laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello people here is my code below for laravel `routes.php`

```
            Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    });

    Route::get('bid', function()
    {
      return View::make('bid');
    });
```

this works fine for `http://localhost/supadmin/public/` but does not work for `http://localhost/supadmin/public/bid` ,, what could be the problem?? Iam getting an error `The requested URL /supadmin/public/bid was not found on this server.` i have also configured `.htaccess` to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It works fine like this `http://localhost/supadmin/public/index.php/bid` but iam expecting it to work `http://localhost/supadmin/public/bid`

`php artisan routes` shows

```
+--------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                      | Name        | Action  | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /               |             | Closure |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD bid             |             | Closure |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD bid_history     | bid_history | Closure |                |
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: @ Zander Rootman i have updated question with error message.. thank you..

Comment: Try with `RewriteBase /supadmin/public` after `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put /bid

```
Route::get('/bid', function()
    {
      return View::make('bid');
});
```

Please make sure routes are registered by using **php artisan routes**

and try it serving through **php artisan serve**

**Edit**

You should also try checking your apache setting

add the following code to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
AllowOverride All
```

Restart apache

Comment: serve app using php artisan serve and check, also try php artisan routes is it showing there

Comment: @Saqueib iam serving now.. its taking bit long time...now it works fine for `localhost:8000/bid`

Comment: @Friend always use serve or setup virtualhost in development

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Apache module `mod_rewrite`.

To enable mod_rewrite:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```